# Close Boost Websocket from Server side, C++, tcp::acceptor accept() timeout?

Tags: c++, boost, websocket, pthreads, poco

UPDATE:
Well it appears that I need to address my issue with an asynchronous implementation. I will update my posting with a new direction, once I've completed testing

Original:
I'm currently writing a multiserver application that will collect, share, and request information from multiple machines. In some cases, Machine A will request information from Machine B but will need to send it to Machine C, which will reply to A. Without getting too deep into what the application is going to do I need some help with my client application.

I have my client application designed with two threads. I used this [example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/beast/example/websocket/server/sync/websocket_server_sync.cpp) from boost, as the basis for my design.

Thread one will open a Client Websocket with Machine-A, it will stream a series of data points and commands. Here is a stripped-down version of my code

```
#include "Poco/Clock.h"
#include "Poco/Task.h"
#include "Poco/Thread.h"
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <jsoncons/json.hpp>

namespace beast     = boost::beast;     // from <boost/beast.hpp>
namespace http      = beast::http;      // from <boost/beast/http.hpp>
namespace websocket = beast::websocket; // from <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
namespace net       = boost::asio;      // from <boost/asio.hpp>
using tcp           = net::ip::tcp;     // from <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>

class ResponseChannel : public Poco::Runnable {
    void do_session(tcp::socket socket)
    {
        try {
            websocket::stream<tcp::socket> ws{std::move(socket)};
            ws.set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator(
                [](websocket::response_type& res) {
                    res.set(http::field::server,
                            std::string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) +
                                " websocket-server-sync");
                }));

            ws.accept();

            for (;;) {
                beast::flat_buffer buffer;
                ws.read(buffer);

                if (ws.got_binary()) {
                    // do something
                }
            }
        } catch (beast::system_error const& se) {
            if (se.code() != websocket::error::closed) {
                std::cerr << "do_session1 ->: " << se.code().message()
                          << std::endl;
                return;
            }
        } catch (std::exception const& e) {
            std::cerr << "do_session2 ->: " << e.what() << std::endl;
            return;
        }
    }

    virtual void run()
    {
        auto const address = net::ip::make_address(host);
        auto const port    = static_cast<unsigned short>(respPort);

        try {
            net::io_context ioc{1};
            tcp::acceptor   acceptor{ioc, {address, port}};
            tcp::socket     socket{ioc};

            for (; keep_running;) {
                acceptor.accept(socket);

                std::thread(&ResponseChannel::do_session, this,
                            std::move(socket))
                    .detach();
            }
        } catch (const std::exception& e) {
            std::cout << "run: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void _terminate() { keep_running = false; }

  public:
    std::string                host;
    int                        respPort;
    bool                       keep_running  = true;
    int                        responseCount = 0;
    std::vector<long long int> latency_times;
    long long int              time_sum;
    Poco::Clock*               responseClock;
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    Poco::Clock     clock = Poco::Clock();
    Poco::Thread    response_thread;
    ResponseChannel response_channel;

    response_channel.responseClock = &clock;
    response_channel.host          = "0.0.0.0";
    response_channel.respPort      = 8080;
    response_thread.start(response_channel);
    response_thread.setPriority(Poco::Thread::Priority::PRIO_HIGH);

    // doing some work here. work will vary depending on command-line arguments
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(30s);
    response_channel.keep_running = false;
    response_thread.join();
}
```

The way I have designed the multiple machines works as expected regarding sending commands to Machine-B and receiving results from Machine-C.

The issue I'm facing is closing out Thread 2, which contains my local response channel.

I went back and forth between Poco::Thread and Poco::Task, but I decided that I do not want to use Task, as it would be a mistake to be able to close the 2nd thread/task from the main thread. I need to know that all packets have been received before closing down the 2nd thread.

So I need to close events down only once I have received a websocket::error::closed flag from Machine-C. Shutting down the websocket, detached, thread is no issue, as when the flag arrives it takes care of that for me.

However, as part of the loop process for reconnecting after a closed socket, the thread just waits for a new connection.

```
acceptor.accept(socket);
```

It's blocking, and through the documentation, there doesn't seem to be a timeout feature. I see that there is a close option, but my attempt to use close simply threw an exception. Which ultimately added complexity, I didn't want.

Ultimately, I want the Server to continuously loop through a series of connections from both Machine-B and Machine-C, but only after my client application has ended. The last thing I do before waiting for the Poco::Thread to complete is to set the flag that I no longer want the Websocket server to run.

I've put that flag before the blocking accept() call. This would work, only with perfect timing of the flag going up, a new connection is opened and then closed, before looping back to wait for a new connection.

Ideally, there would be a timeout so that it would loop around, first checking if it timed out, allow for a periodic check if I wanted the thread to remain open.

Has anyone ever run into this?

Comment: I don't get what's being asked. Accept blocking is not an issue. What socket gets closed? The acceptor? Why would you need to cancel the accept? If so, why not make it asynchronous?

Comment: In general I think everything is overcomplicated in terms of threading. With a bit of asynchrony (you know, as Asio intends) you can probably serve everything, more efficiently and more reliably from a single thread.

Comment: Hello @sehe. Thanks 4 commenting. I'm not sure of your reference to Asio. I'll dig into that & see what I can find. However, regarding Accept blocking. I would like to find a way to prevent accept() from blocking or a way to trigger it to come out of the block. I need to be able to check for a flag to determine if I should wait for new connections or close the client software.  Ultimately, I believe I need at least 2 threads, as the 1st thread will open a websocket from Machine-A to B. While the 2nd thread will handle the connection from Machine-C. Not sure how I would get around that.

Comment: As long as you want to write synchronous code, there is no way around. The goal of asynchrony is concurrency without threading.

Comment: @sehe, thank you. I will look at an asynchronous implementation of the code and update with my results.